# Help understanding second derivative and how they tell us about the features of the original function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

To aid in sketching graphs:

- We can find axial intercepts, asymptotes
- The first derivative can give us the function's stationary points by evaluating $f'(x) = 0$

I know that second derivative give the rate of change of the first derivative

But, what does the second derivative do to help us sketch the original function?

Lets take an example:

- $f(x) = -x^2$
- $f'(x) = -2x$
- $f''(x) = -2$

By evaluating $-2x=0$, we get a turning point at $x = 0$.

Now, what can I do with $f''(x)$ in this case, considering that it is just a constant?

Comment: At each point of a curve, its second derivative and curvature, if nonzero, have the same sign. This gives information about [whether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative) it is concave up or concave down there.

Answer (score 1):

one of the important things that the second derivative tells us is the property of turning point. For example, if the second derivative of the zero of the first derivative is bigger than $0$, then the turning point is the minimal value locally.

As the function $y＝x^2$, whose second derivative of $0$ is $2＞0$. Hence, $0$ is the minimal point of the original function locally (of course, in this function, it's actually the globally minimal）